# Bind render result to texture id

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, opengl-es, image-processing

I want to save the result screen of the rendering and then apply another shader on that result, the typical way is to read the screen using **glReadPixels** and then buffer that image to gpu and then apply my effect, so is there a way to bind the screen result to a texture id directory in gpu, instead of retrieving it back to CPU and then buffer it to GPU ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this great tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/).

Basically you need to create a new texture of the size you want, and then use [glDrawBuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffers.xhtml).

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for thanks a lot.